# i need to Remove space between section number and title and make the number section in the right side

Tags: table-of-contents, polyglossia, arabic, mindmaps

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt,oneside, tikz, ignorerest=false]{book}  \usepackage[paperwidth=210mm,paperheight=297mm,hmargin=0.5cm,top=10mm,bottom=23mm]{geometry}
    \usepackage{tikz}
    \usetikzlibrary{mindmap}
    \pagestyle{empty}
    
    \usepackage{etoc}
     %\usepackage{hyperref}% if links are wanted
    \usepackage[pdfstartview=FitH,colorlinks=true,urlcolor=blue,linkcolor=red]{hyperref} 
     \usepackage{polyglossia}
    \setotherlanguage{english}
    \setmainlanguage[numerals=maghrib]{arabic}
    \setotherlanguage{french}
    \newfontfamily\arabicfont[Script=Arabic,Scale=1.2]{Amiri}
    \newfontfamily\frenchfont{Times New Roman}
    \newfontfamily\fontb[Script=Arabic, Scale=0.9]{AlBattar}
    \newfontfamily\fonta[Script=Arabic, Scale=1.2]{AlBattar}
    \newfontfamily\ttfont[Script=Arabic, Scale=1.2]{AlBattar}
    \newfontfamily\myfont[Script=Arabic,Scale=1.3]{Sakkal Majalla}
    \newfontfamily\na[Script=Arabic,Scale=0.9]{Amiri}
    \newfontfamily\naa[Script=Arabic,Scale=0.8]{Amiri}
    \begin{document}
    
    \newtoks\treetok
    \newtoks\chaptertok
    \newtoks\sectiontok
    
    \newcommand*\treenode {}  % just to check we don't overwrite something
    \newcommand*\tmprotate {} % just to check we don't overwrite something
    \newcommand*\tmpoption {} % just to check we don't overwrite something
    \newcommand*\tmpstuff  {} % just to check we don't overwrite something
    
    \newcommand*\appendtotok[2]{% #1=toks variable, #2=macro, expands once #2
      #1\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter{\expandafter\the\expandafter #1#2}}
    
    \newcommand*{\appendchildtree}[3]{% 
    % this is to construct "t1 child [concept color= #3]{t2}" from #1=t1 and #2=t2
    % t1 and t2 are two toks variable (not macros)
    % #3 = for example teal!60
       \edef\tmpstuff {\the#1 child [concept color = #3]{\the#2}}%
       #1\expandafter {\tmpstuff }%
    }
    
    \newcounter{partco}
    
    \etocsetstyle{chapter}
      {}
      {}
      {
      \toks0 \expandafter{\etocthelinkednumber}%
       \toks2 \expandafter{\etocthelinkedname}%
       \stepcounter{partco}%
       \ifcase\value{partco}%
       \or  \def\tmpoption {}%
            \def\tmprotate {[clockwise from = 120]}% first
       \or  \def\tmpoption {}%
            \def\tmprotate {[clockwise from = 60]}% second
       \else\def\tmpoption {\textarabic{}}%
            \def\tmprotate {[counterclockwise from = 90]}% third and higher
       \fi
    % define the part node
       \edef\treenode{node \tmpoption{\the\toks2} \tmprotate }%
    % this is a starting point which will be filled it by the section children
       \chaptertok\expandafter{\treenode}
       }
      {}
    %\etocsetstyle{chapter}
    %  {\etocskipfirstprefix}
    %  {\appendchildtree\treetok\chaptertok}
    %  {\preparetreenode
    %   \chaptertok\expandafter{\treenode}}
    %  {\appendchildtree\treetok\chaptertok}
    
    
    
    
    
    
    
    
    
    
    
    \etocsetstyle{section}
      {}
      {}
      {\toks0 \expandafter{\etocthelinkednumber}%
       \toks2 \expandafter{\etocthelinkedname }%
    % define the section node
       \edef\treenode {node {\the\toks2 \space\the\toks0}}
       \sectiontok\expandafter{\treenode}%
    % update current part tree with this section node, adding the correct color
       \ifcase\value{partco}%
       \or \appendchildtree\chaptertok\sectiontok {teal!30}% first
       \or \appendchildtree\chaptertok\sectiontok {yellow!40}% second
       \or \appendchildtree\chaptertok\sectiontok {red!80}
       \else\appendchildtree\chaptertok\sectiontok {green!30}% third etc...
       \fi }
    % This updates the global tree with the data  from the
    % part and all its children sections
      {\ifcase\value{partco}%
       \or \appendchildtree\treetok\chaptertok {teal!60}%   first
       \or \appendchildtree\treetok\chaptertok {yellow!80}% second
       \or \appendchildtree\treetok\chaptertok {red!80}% second   
       \else\appendchildtree\treetok\chaptertok {green!50}% third and next ...
       \fi
       }
    
    \etocsettocstyle
      {\treetok{\node{\textbf{\textarabic{العنواين الرئيسية}}} [clockwise from=45]}}
      {\global\appendtotok\treetok{ ;}}
    % The \global above is mandatory because etoc always typesets TOC inside a group
    
    \tableofcontents
    
    % \showthe\treetok % debugging
    
    \begin{tikzpicture}[rotate=90, grow cyclic, text width=2cm, 
                        align=flush center, 
                        every node/.style=concept, 
                        concept color=orange!60,
                        level 1/.style={level distance=5cm,sibling angle=90},
                        level 2/.style={rotate=-30,level distance=4cm,sibling angle=45}]
    
    \the\treetok
\end{tikzpicture}


\chapter {\textarabic{العنوان الرئيسي الاول}}
\section {\textarabic{العنوان الاول}}
\section {العنوان الثاني }
\section {\textarabic{العنوان الثالث}}


\chapter {العنوان الرئيسي الثاني }
\section {العنوان الفرعي الاول}
\section {العنوان الثاني}
\section {العنوان الثاني}

\end{document}
```

Comment: are you using lualatex or xelatex?

Comment: your image does not seem to match the pasted code for chapters which uses only `\toks2` which contains the name, and not `\toks0` which contains the number, but your image appears to have chapter numbers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have the fonts so I tested your example with

```
    % \newfontfamily\arabicfont[Script=Arabic,Scale=1.2]{Amiri}
    % \newfontfamily\frenchfont{Times New Roman}
    % \newfontfamily\fontb[Script=Arabic, Scale=0.9]{AlBattar}
    % \newfontfamily\fonta[Script=Arabic, Scale=1.2]{AlBattar}
    % \newfontfamily\ttfont[Script=Arabic, Scale=1.2]{AlBattar}
    % \newfontfamily\myfont[Script=Arabic,Scale=1.3]{Sakkal Majalla}
    % \newfontfamily\na[Script=Arabic,Scale=0.9]{Amiri}
    % \newfontfamily\naa[Script=Arabic,Scale=0.8]{Amiri}
    \newfontfamily\arabicfont[Script=Arabic,Scale=1.2]{Al Tarikh}
    \newfontfamily\frenchfont{Times New Roman}
    \newfontfamily\fontb[Script=Arabic, Scale=0.9]{Al Tarikh}
    \newfontfamily\fonta[Script=Arabic, Scale=1.2]{Al Tarikh}
    \newfontfamily\ttfont[Script=Arabic, Scale=1.2]{Al Tarikh}
    \newfontfamily\myfont[Script=Arabic,Scale=1.3]{Al Tarikh}
    \newfontfamily\na[Script=Arabic,Scale=0.9]{Al Tarikh}
    \newfontfamily\naa[Script=Arabic,Scale=0.8]{Al Tarikh}
```

as Al Tarikh is available on my mac os as system font. Compiling with XeLaTeX I see some strange fontspec warning:

```
Package fontspec Warning: Font "Al Tarikh" does not contain requested Script
(fontspec)                "Arabic".
```

but the output may be ok: (caveat I don't read arabic, so apologies in advance)

[image: xelatex altarikh]

The lines commanding this appear to be the following

```
      {\toks0 \expandafter{\etocthelinkednumber}%
       \toks2 \expandafter{\etocthelinkedname }%
    % define the section node
       \edef\treenode {node {\the\toks2 \space\the\toks0}}
```

in the `\etocsetstyle{section}` hunk.  So it already says to put the number on right, but perhaps it should actually be in output this opposite due to LTR ? maybe my output is all wrong... notice here the section numbers are below only due to the width which happens to shift them to a second line.

You can thus try to play with the order of things in the line

```
 \edef\treenode {node {\the\toks2 \space\the\toks0}}
```

and use some TikZ syntax here perhaps to manage the node width.

Another fontspec warning is

```
Missing character: There is no ‏ (U+200F) in font Al Tarikh Regular/OT:language
=dflt;!
```

Finally, trying lualatex gives an altogether different output:

[image: lualatex output]

No idea if this is TikZ problem or RTL rendering problem.

---

Back to xelatex and integrating these comments:

> I need the section nombre before the section not after

> locate the line after `% define the section node` which is `\edef\treenode {node {\the\toks2 \space\the\toks0}}` and replace it with `\edef\treenode {node {\the\toks0 \noexpand\hspace{3mm}\the\toks2}}`

> i added a `\hspace` so you can configure spacing.  The `\noexpand` is because this is in an `\edef` but expansion must be delayed.  Also, I am assuming you still want RTL for the section number so `1.1`, `2.1`, `3.1` and not `1.1`, `1.2`, `1.3`.

Output:

[image]

Comment: I need the section nombre before the section not after

Comment: see updated answer.  If you need the section numbers to use LTR typesetting you may use `\edef\treenode {node {{\noexpand\textfrench{\the\toks0}}\noexpand\hspace{3mm}\the\toks2}}` rather.

Comment: I finde the. Solution withe \RL \edef\treenode {node 
 {\RL {{\noexpand\textfrench{\the\toks0}}\noexpand\hspace{3mm}\the\toks2}}}

Comment: right to left is too challenging to me; good that  you solved it for yourself

Comment: I sloved it Withe your solution